# how to move the button in Xcode above the screen

Tags: xcode, user-interface, button

How to move the stop button above the screen without affecting the stack view,and also without affecting the structure of the stack view?

[image]

Comment: change top constraint's constant to -8 instead 8.

Comment: @Kamran.  But than affects my stack view

Comment: The stop button needs to exist outside the context of the stack view.

Comment: @InfinityJames. Outside stack view but inside the screen

Answer (score 0):

Check if the stop button is embedded in the stack view. If it is, un-embed it by selecting the stack view, Editor -> Unembed stack view, and create it again, making sure not to include the button in the stack view.